# Не добавляются элементы, не присваиваются классы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток видимо в чём-то не разобрался, но в документации ответ найти не смог, почему не работают такие вот вещи:

```
td = document.createElement('td');
td.addClass("value");
td.append("<label><input class='number1'></label>");
```

Ну а точнее 2 и 3 строчки?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Работа с классами элемента производится с помощью свойства [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

- `element.classList.add('class')` — добавление класса
- `element.classList.remove('class')` — удаление класса
- [полный список методов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B)

---

Добавить произвольный html код в конец элемента можно с помощью свойства [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```
element.innerHTML += "<label><input class='number1'></label>";
```

---

Если вы хотите использовать [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) методы [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) и [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/), то вам надо получить jQuery обёртку элемента:

```
$(element)
```

и работать с ней. В вашем случае:

```
td = $(document.createElement('td'));
...
```

Comment: я прошу прощения а можно тогда ещё один вопрос, почему в данном случае не работает присвоение класс, вроде же использовал обёртку. Точнее даже не не работает, а проблема с присваиваемой функцией, в DOM это класс высвечивается, но свои функции не выполняет.

Comment: $('.number2').bind("keyup", function() {
      if(this.value.match(/[,]/g))this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g , ".");
      if (this.value.match(/[^0-9/./,]/g)) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9/./,]/g, '');
      }});

Comment: function builder (){
      $("#bigTable").empty();
     var rows = $("#rows").val();
     var cols = $("#cols").val();

Comment: var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');
     for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
         var row = $('<tr></tr>');
         for(var j=0; j<cols; j++){
          var col = $('<td><label><input class="number2"></label></td>');
          row.append(col);
         }
         table.append(row);
     }
      $('#bigTable').append(table);
     }

Comment: эм последнии 2 комментария это одна функция, просто не поместилась (

Comment: @Owl если честно код в комментариях сложно читать, лучше задайте новый вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: хорошо ) 40 мин пройдёт и выложу, а то чаще не разрешает. Спасибо огромное за то что подсказали как работать с добавлением элементов.

Answer (score 1):

`addClass` и `append` - методы объекта-обертки jQuery.

```
td = $(document.createElement('td'));
td.addClass("value");
td.append("<label><input class='number1'></label>");
```

Comment: `$(document.createElement('td'));` => `$('<td>');`